# html code showing up in php string

Tags: php

I am using var_dump to output a string but the length is different then what is showing so I printed out each character and found there are the hidden html codes #40; and #41; in the string attributing to the length. These are causing problems in an sql statement so I am trying to remove them, but htmlspecialchars_decode, and urldecode do not remove the characters. How can I get ride of these codes? The value is coming from a database is utf-8 (CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin) and does not have any html codes stored in it (stored as "Civic (sedan)" in table).

```
//this is the output of the string
Civic (#40;sedan)#41;
echo var_dump($data['model']).'<br>';

//output
string(21) "Civic (sedan)" 

echo var_dump(strip_tags($data['model'])).'<br>';

//output
string(21) "Civic (sedan)" 

echo var_dump(htmlspecialchars_decode($data['model'])).'<br>';

//output
string(21) "Civic (sedan)" 

echo var_dump(urldecode($data['model'])).'<br>';

//output
string(21) "Civic (sedan)"
```

Comment: Could you not do an str_replace(); ?

Comment: I could but then I would have to string replace other characters as well, which I do not know are stored in a database of 60,000 records

Comment: you would need to replace a massive array unless you knew for certain all cases. preg_replace would be better

Comment: Are you really really sure, that those characters are not stored in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is what you are after, I think...

Comment: But that would convert `Civic (#40;sedan)#41;` into `Civic ((sedan))`. But maybe the given output was mistyped.